# Can't access ec2 instance via fsockopen in PHP pointed at my ec2 public IP and designated port

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket

Before anything else, I have read about 30+ StackOverflow answers and none of them seem to address my particular flavour of this problem. Below I list all the answers I have already tried before asking for more advice.

I am trying to access my ec2 instance via socket in PHP from a different machine via fsockopen, pointed at my ec2 public IP (I have an Elastic fixed IP address 54.68.166.28) and designated port.

Behaviour: I can access the instance and the ChatScript application running inside from within the instance, via the public IP directly on the browser. But if I run the exact same webpage with the exact same socket call on an external machine targeting my instance's IP address (double checked it is the correct one) I get a 500 Internal Server Error when connecting on port 1024 (for my custom TCP connection), another 500 on port 443 (HTTPS). On port 80 (HTTP) it hangs 20+ seconds then gives me status 200 success, except it does not connect properly to the application and responds with nothing.

Troubleshooting:
I have set up my security group rules to accept incoming TCP from anywhere:
HTTP (80)   TCP     80  0.0.0.0/0
HTTP (80)   TCP 80  ::/0
HTTPS (443) TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS (443) TCP  443    ::/0
Custom (1024)   TCP 1024    0.0.0.0/0
Custom (1024)   TCP  1024   ::/0

Outbound rules span port range 0 - 65535 with destination 0.0.0.0/0, so should work.

I ssh every time without problems into the instance on port 22. SCP also works fine.
Checked $sudo service httpd status: running, which is why my UI displays there fine.
Checked $sudo /sbin/iptables -L and all my policies are set to ACCEPT with no rules
Checked $ netstat --listen -p and the app I am targeting is listening on port 0.0.0.0.0:1024. 
Checked Network Utility and ports 80 and 1024 are registered as open. Port 443 is not. Pinging did not work for any of them, with 100% packet loss.

Checked my instance is associated to the security group with all the permissions - it is. IP is clearly correct or I could neither ssh nor serve webpages... which I can.

I stopped and restarted the instance.

I replaced the instance.

I think this is due diligence before asking for help... now I need it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my configuration was correct: the problem was that the hosted domain I used for the GUI, like most hosted domains, does not open custom ports, so tcp did not work.